# Creating a generalised onChange() function for different inputs without the use of name tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to create a generalized `handleChange()` function for all my input fields. I have over 30 input fields, so there is not really an option to have one handleChange method for each input, as this would create tons of boilerplate code. In the example below I have tried to create a function that will handle any input.

For my project, I'm using Ant design, which does not seem to support the name attribute inside their form elements (e.g. InputNumber/Input, etc.)

Example of an InputNumber field:

```
<InputNumber name='myNumber' min={1} max={100000} placeholder='Enter number'  value={this.state.myNumber} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

This is my attempt at writing a generalized onChange method. But it passes this error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
 handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
```

This method would allow me to reach any selected input element and update that specific one. However, this does work due to the lack of a name attribute.

As suggested below, this approach works, but still leaves me without a generalized solution - a way to handle any input and map to the correct state value.

```
state = {
    myNumber: 0,
    myNumber2: 0,
    myNumber3: 0
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      myNumber: e
    });
  };
```

In the example below the `handleChange` function will only update `myNumber`, not `myNumber2` and `myNumber3`.

```
<InputNumber name='myNumber' min={1} max={100000} placeholder='Enter number'  value={this.state.myNumber} onChange={handleChange}/>
<InputNumber name='myNumber2' min={1} max={100000} placeholder='Enter number'  value={this.state.myNumber2} onChange={handleChange}/>
<InputNumber name='myNumber3' min={1} max={100000} placeholder='Enter number'  value={this.state.myNumber3} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Any suggestions to a workaround?

Comment: As of now, my only suggested solution is to rebuild my project using Material-UI. I have tested this function on a project using Material UI, and it worked because they support the 'name' attribute.

I way prefer the design og Ant Design, so I would still appreciate a workaround, if possible.

Comment: Your question is too abroad, what does "generalized onChange method" means? How you aspect your component to behave? Check my answer although I think you should elaborate more with specific examples.

Comment: Moreover, "my only suggested solution is to rebuild my project using Material-UI" is a very bad suggestion, refactoring a project because "lack of knowledge" is a piece of bad advice.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful comment! I have tried to specify my problem further in the original post.

Comment: SHOW usage example, try to read your question, do you think people can understand what you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is my first time using stack overflow, I'm not used to describing my issues like this. I will go through my post again.

Comment: Great now its clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`InputNumber` API](https://ant.design/components/input-number/#API), `onChange` accepts a `Number|String`, `e.target.value` will always resolve run time error.

> onChange: The callback triggered when the value is changed -  function(value: number | string)

Here is an example, where I suppose in writing:

```
<InputNumber name='myNumber' min={1} max={100000} placeholder='Enter number'  value={this.state.myNumber} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

You meant using a class component, because `onChange={handleChange}` as you described must be a part of a class.

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    myNumber: 0
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      myNumber: e
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlexBox>
        <InputNumber
          name="myNumber"
          min={1}
          max={100000}
          placeholder="Enter number"
          value={this.state.myNumber}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </FlexBox>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-56934468-InputNumber]

---

- If you want to use a generic method `handleChange` you should change the component type from `InputNumber` to `Input`, that's because you want to access `name="myNumber"` property.

```
handleChange = e => {
  e.persist();
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
};
```

- A better approach keeps using `InputNumber` and implement `handleChange` as curried function:

```
handleChange = name => e => {
  this.setState({
    [name]: e
  });
};
```

Check the [example](https://rcmtx.codesandbox.io/) of both approaches:

```js
class AppInputNumber extends React.Component {
  state = {
    myNumber: 0,
    myNumber2: 0,
    myNumber3: 0
  };

  handleChange = name => e => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: e
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlexBox>
        <InputNumber
          min={1}
          max={100000}
          placeholder="Enter number"
          value={this.state.myNumber}
          onChange={this.handleChange('myNumber')}
        />
        <InputNumber
          min={1}
          max={100000}
          placeholder="Enter number"
          value={this.state.myNumber2}
          onChange={this.handleChange('myNumber2')}
        />
        <InputNumber
          min={1}
          max={100000}
          placeholder="Enter number"
          value={this.state.myNumber3}
          onChange={this.handleChange('myNumber3')}
        />
      </FlexBox>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    myNumber: 0,
    myNumber2: 0,
    myNumber3: 0
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlexBox>
        <Input
          name="myNumber"
          min={1}
          max={100000}
          type="number"
          placeholder="Enter number"
          value={this.state.myNumber}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <Input
          name="myNumber2"
          min={1}
          max={100000}
          type="number"
          placeholder="Enter number"
          value={this.state.myNumber2}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <Input
          name="myNumber3"
          min={1}
          max={100000}
          type="number"
          placeholder="Enter number"
          value={this.state.myNumber3}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <AppInputNumber />
      </FlexBox>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-56934468-GenericHandle]

---

Comment: Thanks, for the reply! This lets me reach the value, but my goal is to create a generalised handleChange method. How would you suggest I do this with this method?

Comment: What does it mean generalized method? Edit your question and add an usage example, expected behaviour, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Denis! I have tried to update my original post to be more specific.

Comment: Answer updated, if it was helpful, please accept the answer and upvote. Moreover please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take a read of [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for your next post ;-) Have fun.

Comment: Dennis Vash, you are legend. It worked perfectly, thanks!

 I'm sorry, but I only have 6 reputation, so my upvote is not visualized, but recorded.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but if the `e` is an event object, try this

`e.target.getAttribute('name')`